# Quarkus + Native Image memory usage

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm-native-image, smallrye

I am evaluating Quarkus and I have quite simple app built as a Native Image. In the app I have Smallreye Metrics. Everything works fine, but I am not able to reason about memory usage reported by Smallrye and by Docker.

When I run docker stats, I get

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
6510f3adb51b        lucid_newton        0.01%               4.668MiB / 10MiB    46.68%              15kB / 81.3kB       0B / 0B             26
```

So 4.6MB, cool.

When I take a look into Smallrye output `/metrics`, I see

```
# HELP base_memory_usedHeap_bytes Displays the amount of used heap memory in bytes.
# TYPE base_memory_usedHeap_bytes gauge
base_memory_usedHeap_bytes 1.5272E7
# HELP vendor_memory_committedNonHeap_bytes Displays the amount of non heap memory in bytes that is committed for the Java virtual machine to use.
# TYPE vendor_memory_committedNonHeap_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_committedNonHeap_bytes 1.2715696E7
# HELP vendor_memory_maxNonHeap_bytes Displays the maximum amount of used non-heap memory in bytes.
# TYPE vendor_memory_maxNonHeap_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_maxNonHeap_bytes -1.0
# HELP vendor_memory_usedNonHeap_bytes Displays the amount of used non-heap memory in bytes.
# TYPE vendor_memory_usedNonHeap_bytes gauge
vendor_memory_usedNonHeap_bytes 1.2715696E7
```

Which is roughtly 10 times more (if I read the scientific notation correctly). What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find out what causes this ?Because I’ve noticed the same and my guess is that the metrics are not working correctly when in native mode somehow.

Comment: unfortunatelly I have not found any answer to this issue.